# Reading individuel pixels from an Image in PlayN

Tags: canvas, playn

I am working on a small project involving PlayN.
I am trying to make my own BitmapFont class where I need to be able to read individuel pixels from an Image, so I can hack up my image into letters.
I can not seem to find any methods on Image or CanvasImage which allows me to do this.

Is there any other way I can achieve this in PlayN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off doing whatever processing is needed to identify the glyphs in a bitmap font ahead of time and storing the metadata in a JSON file associated with the font image. Then at runtime your game would just load in the font image and the JSON metadata file and use the metadata to determine the bounds of each individual glyph.

You can do your preprocessing using standard Java classes like ImageIO and BufferedImage.

That said, it would probably not be too onerous to add a getColor(int x, int y) method to Canvas, as I believe the technology that underlies Canvas on each of the different supported platforms provides a way to read a pixel from the image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suspect that images on all platforms should have some sort of getColor(x,y) method which should be available in Image or CanvasImage in PlayN.
You are probably right that I could probably use some preprocessing to store the font glyphs in JSON, but I feel that this would not suit my need for some sweet looking fonts dressed up in Photoshop.